# Set folders writable to joomla installation

Tags: security, joomla, permissions, chmod, chown

I have a jommla website but i have some issues with the permissions.

There is any problem if I set 777 recursively to these folders in terms of security?

```
/public_html/tmp
/public_html/logs
/public_html/images
/public_html/cache
/public_html/administrator/cache
```

If I set to 755 all folders, they still not writable to joomla. Only with 777. This can be an ownership problem? Or i am fine with 777 in the specified folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a very bad idea to set any folders to 777 as it poses security threats due to the fact that it enables read, write and execute permissions. All folders should be 755 and files should be 644.

This website give some very god examples of security issues:

http://www.anchor.com.au/blog/2012/09/the-chmod-777-trap-how-and-why-to-avoid-it/

The reason why it still might not be writable is due to folder ownership. To sort this out, you will need to talk to your host.